# Are Somebody knows how to rotate liveviewOrientation in Sony Camera remote API

Tags: android, sony-camera-api

I'm using the Sony Camera API for taking a picture remotely, but when I rotate the camera streaming image is still vertical. API ver. is 2.40. I checked the Reference of API but there is nothing about orientation of live view

Answer (score 1):

Look to api getevent  (pooling or callback) , you will see a liveviewOrientation value in the result.

{
"type":"liveviewOrientation",
"liveviewOrientation":"90"
}

Then you have to rotate your output stream.

It's device dependant

Rotate:

Read the stream, look for Common Header to decode "Packet",then extract JPEG image from one "Packet",decode it.
Rotate the image according to liveviewOrientation, then show it to your display.

Comment: Yea, I check the API and found liveviewOrientation, my question was how can I rotate with getevent value? @FrLa